# Images won't align in a line

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I have 3 images that have a hover attribute, and that will act as a hyperlink to another page on my website. However, I can not figure out how to position the 3 images onto the same line. Here is [a jsFiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/sugarcraving/y9GXs/) with the code.

HTML:

```html
<div class="view view-sixth" style="margin-bottom:30px">
     <img src="champions/mode/ashe.jpg">
     <div class="mask">
     <h2>1</h2>
     <p>1</p>
         <a href="http://www.google.com" class="info" target="_blank">Google</a>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="view view-sixth" style="margin-bottom:30px">
     <img src="champions/mode/garen.jpg">
     <div class="mask">
     <h2>2</h2>
     <p>2</p>
         <a href="http://www.google.com" class="info" target="_blank">Google</a>
     </div>
</div>


<div class="view view-sixth" style="margin-bottom:30px">
     <img src="champions/mode/ryze.jpg">
     <div class="mask">
     <h2>3</h2>
     <p>3</p>
          <a href="http://www.google.com" class="info" target="_blank">Google</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.view-sixth img {
   -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0.5s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0.5s;
   -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0.5s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0.5s;
   transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0.5s;

}
.view-sixth .mask {
   background: rgba(146,96,91,0.5);
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in 0.2s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in 0.2s;
   -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in 0.2s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in 0.2s;
   transition: all 0.2s ease-in 0.2s;

}
.view-sixth h2 {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   background: transparent;
   margin: 20px 40px 0px 40px;
   -webkit-transform: scale(10);
   -moz-transform: scale(10);
   -o-transform: scale(10);
   -ms-transform: scale(10);
   transform: scale(10);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;

}
.view-sixth p {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transform: scale(10);
   -moz-transform: scale(10);
   -o-transform: scale(10);
   -ms-transform: scale(10);
   transform: scale(10);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;

}
.view-sixth a.info {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   opacity: 0;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(100px);
   -o-transform: translateY(100px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(100px);
   transform: translateY(100px);
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;

}
.view-sixth:hover .mask {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
   -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
   -o-transition-delay: 0s;
   -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
   transition-delay: 0s;


}
.view-sixth:hover img {
   -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
   -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
   -o-transition-delay: 0s;
   -ms-transition-delay: 0s;
   transition-delay: 0s;


}
.view-sixth:hover h2 {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   -moz-transform: scale(1);
   -o-transform: scale(1);
   -ms-transform: scale(1);
   transform: scale(1);
   -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
   -moz-transition-delay: 0.1s;
   -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
   -ms-transition-delay: 0.1s;
   transition-delay: 0.1s;

}
.view-sixth:hover p {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1);
   -moz-transform: scale(1);
   -o-transform: scale(1);
   -ms-transform: scale(1);
   transform: scale(1);
   -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
   -moz-transition-delay: 0.2s;
   -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
   -ms-transition-delay: 0.2s;
   transition-delay: 0.2s;

}
.view-sixth:hover a.info {
   -ms-filter: "progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
   filter: alpha(opacity=100);
   opacity: 1;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
   -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
   -o-transform: translateY(0px);
   -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
   transform: translateY(0px);
   -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
   -moz-transition-delay: 0.3s;
   -o-transition-delay: 0.3s;
   -ms-transition-delay: 0.3s;
   transition-delay: 0.3s;

}

.view {
   width: 260px;
   height: 390px;
   border:  solid purple;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px purple;
   cursor: default;


}
.view .mask,.view .content {
   width: 260px;
   height: 390px;
   position: absolute;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
   overflow: hidden;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;

}
.view img {
   display: block;
   position: relative;

}
.view h2 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   position: relative;
   font-family: Candara;
   font-size: 20px;
   padding: 30px;
}
.view p {
   font-family: Candara, serif;
   font-size: 20px;
   position: relative;
   color: white;
   padding: 10px 20px 20px;
   text-align: center;
}
.view a.info {
   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 7px 14px;
   background: white;
   color: black;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
   box-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
   border-radius: 5px;
}
.view a.info:hover {
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}
```

Can anyone give me some pointers?

---

**Edit**: Thank you all for your responses. My problem is now fixed. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float: left;` to the `.view` rule set:

```css
.view {
   width: 260px;
   height: 390px;
   border: solid #800080;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #800080;
   cursor: default;
   float: left; /* ← add this */
}
```

[A fixed jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/PKMXj/)

Comment: Sorry, one more question. What code should i use to center the 3 images?

Comment: If you work your way using padding option doesn't it work? I can't see the full image or even the fiddle to work on that.

Comment: I was thinking of using margin and the auto value to keep the images centered relative to the browser size, but i'm not sure how or where to put the code. Here is the jsfiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/sugarcraving/y9GXs/4/

Comment: To center the 3 images in the page you need to create a container div to wrap your 3 .view divs, and give it the width of your 3 divs combined and add the margin: 0 auto;
So you will have a container div with 800px (more or less) width and margin 0 auto; http://jsfiddle.net/mb2R5/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

By adding this:

```
.view-sixth {
    display:inline-block;
width:33%;    
}
```

it solved the problem for me :D

Comment: [That solution](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/rX3rB/) doesn't work for me on Firefox 22. Only two of the boxes are on one line, and the boxes are misaligned with the black hover overlays.

Comment: this : -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
 box-sizing: border-box; should fix it.

Comment: or you can fix the witdh manually in pixel if it don't need to be responsive.

Answer (score 0):

To your view class rule, add `float:left;`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/y9GXs/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

All you need is `float: left` on the `.view` div

Have a look at - http://jsfiddle.net/8P7rB/

```
.view {
   width: 260px;
   height: 390px;
   border:  solid purple;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px purple;
   cursor: default;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the CSS `display` property of the `div`s that include the images to `inline-block`:

```css
.view {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roryokane/etmph/)

The images should be aligned if there is enough space. If you want the images to always be aligned even if there is not enough space, include them in a container and set the container’s `min-width`.